# removing the "\n" for every line except for the last line

Tags: python, io

Currently I have a test.txt

```
1234
5678
```

I want to print out each line without the newline char "\n"

```
file=open("test.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
for i in lines:
    print i[:-1]
```

this will remove the \n for the first line, but for the second line: `5678`, the `8` will be cut off because there is no `\n` after it. What is a good way to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

```
for i in lines:
    print i.rstrip('\n')
```

This will remove the newline from each line (if there is one). `rstrip` on its own will remove *all* trailing whitespace, not just newlines.

For example:

```
>>> 'foobar\n'.rstrip('\n')
foobar
>>> 'foobar'.rstrip('\n')
foobar
>>> 'foobar  \t \n'.rstrip()
foobar
```

Related are [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), which strips from both ends, and [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip), which strips from the left only.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

`i.rstrip()` will strip all whitespace from the right, `i.rstrip('\n')` just the newlines.